# Protractor get div by title that contains white spaces

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I'm trying to click a toolbar button.
I want to find this element by its title.

Element:

```
<div class="dhx_toolbar_btn dhxtoolbar_btn_def" title="Create New Index">
<img src="/public/images/toolbar/add.png">
</div>
```

I cannot get the title because it has whitespaces in it. I can get the title if I remove the whitespaces.
But I cannot remove the whitespaces how can I get this element?

Code to get:

```
$$('.dhxtoolbar_float_left').get(0).$('div[title=Create New Index]').click();
```

Error:

```
 Failed: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

Comment: @Pete This is the toolbar div where all the div buttons are inside:
<div class="dhxtoolbar_float_left"><div class="dhx_toolbar_btn dhxtoolbar_btn_def" title="Create New Index">
<img src="/public/images/toolbar/add.png">
</div></div>

Comment: If you use in predicate attribute value with spaces, you need to add quotes: `[title="Create New Index"]`. I don't know why @Murthi deleted the answer as it seem to be correct...

Comment: @Sundaze While you raise a question consider providing the **exact HTML as it is** and as additional info mention : `I can get the title if I remove the whitespaces`. Let the volunteers work on the raw information/data.

Comment: @Andersson That's the solution thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give it inside quotes if value have spaces as given below.

```
$$('.dhxtoolbar_float_left').get(0).$('div[title="Create New Index"]').click();
```

Comment: I found that, quotes are missing in that, hence answered. only sundaze can validate my answer. How do you validate without full html page?

Comment: @Pete,  In the link, the parent element class is different. where you got from? <div class="dhx_toolbar_btn dhxtoolbar_btn_def">
  <div class="dhx_toolbar_btn dhxtoolbar_btn_def" title="Create New Index">
    <img src="/public/images/toolbar/add.png">test should be red
  </div>
</div>